# Bit bang ATmega328 with Arduino bootloader using AVRDUDE

Tags: arduino, avr, avrdude, bootloader, atmega

I have an Arduino Uno development board with a blank ATmega328 chip (no Arduino bootloader. The chip that came with the unit is soldered in a separate stand-alone project so that I can use the Arduino board for more than one instance :) )

So looking [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/how-to-burn-atmega328-chip-via-arduino-uno-as-isp), the Uno isn't able to program the chip as it cannot be used as an ISP (yet?).

Would I be able to use AVRDUDE in a bit-bang programmer mode and hook up the ATmega's SPI lines to my serial port (using the correct lines obviously) and program the bootloader? I've seen topics on the web that say this is possible to do with other AVR chips, but I'm just really a noob here trying to get by. I understand that I can purchase an AVR ISP for ~US$20 to do so, but I was hoping to get started on a project tomorrow/tonight and do not want this weekend to go wasted (waiting for it to arrive...).

Anyone have a good reference on how to proceed?

To clear up some confusion, I am trying to program an ATmega328 with an Arduino bootloader. I only have the Uno development board and a blank ATmega328. I do have a serial port and really do not want to wait for an AVRISP to come in as I would like to get started sooner rather than later. Is this possible with the ATmega328? How would I proceed?

Comment: How about making one of the countless serial AVR programmers and using it to write the Arduino firmware? [This](http://electronics-diy.com/avr_programmer.php) one worked for me, but I have USB to serial converter, so it works at amazing 3 B/s. If the programer lines on your other project are available, you can dump firmware using AVRdude. You could also probably get it form the Internet, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, that first link is what I was looking for. If you would put that as an answer, I'd be willing to mark it correct. I'm pretty new to the embedded world and a simple yet effective tutorial like that link is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just FYI, tons of AVR ISP clones are sold for ~$2-$5 on e-bay and similar sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making one of the countless serial AVR programmers and using it to write the Arduino firmware? [This](http://electronics-diy.com/avr_programmer.php) one worked for me, but I have USB to serial converter, so it works at amazing 3 B/s. If the programer lines on your other project are available, you can dump firmware using AVRdude. You could also probably get it form the Internet, but I don't know where to look

Comment: 3 B/s?  That *is* amazing!

Comment: @reemrevnivek♦ Yes, especially when I want to upload a 10K program into it. In retrospective, this made me debug much more before burning programs into EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

With Arduino Uno it is not possible.

Try with Arduino Duemilanove. I use they and link process and work. 
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

Comment: Actually it is reportedly possible by a variety of means, such as a 120 or so ohm resistor between the reset line and the logic supply.  There's also a sketch floating around where the bootloader payload is built in, so no communication is required, avoiding the reset issue.  It's a shame Arduino hasn't updated that now overly pessimistic page.

Answer (score 0):

AVR chips can only be recorded once, once recorded you have to delete them by deleting the fuse, this can only be done with HV programmers, once deleted you can re-program any AVR.