# Can you use an Arduino Uno as an ATmega328 programmer?

Tags: avr, programmer, arduino

I don't have an Uno, but I was thinking of getting one and by the looks of it, you can remove the AVR microcontroller from the Arduino, right? It's just a DIP IC in a socket that can be pulled out, it seems like.

[Uno http://egyrobots.com/image/cache/data/arduino-uno-500x500.jpg](http://egyrobots.com/image/cache/data/arduino-uno-500x500.jpg)

So can you just load a program, remove the AVR chip, throw in another one, and load another program? Then you can have a permanent microcontroller solution for all your projects.

Is this possible?

Comment: duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/how-to-burn-atmega328-chip-via-arduino-uno-as-isp

Comment: The image link is (effectively) broken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the Arduino can be used as an AVR programmer.
But, no, you can't just plug the new chip in.

The AVR microcontroller in the Arduino contains the Arduino bootloader. This bootloader can only update the sketch code.

In order to use a brand new AVR with your Arduino, you'll need to copy the Arduino bootloader to it using an AVR In-System-Programmer (ISP).

Fortunately, the Arduino Uno can be used as an AVR ISP.

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Comment: From the top of the page you link to: "NOTE: Currently, you cannot use an Arduino Uno as an ISP programmer because the optiboot bootloader does not support this sketch. A revision for this is in progress."

Comment: @Nick Thanks, I didn't read it, I just assumed that it was like the older Arduinos. Odd that the bootloader prevents it

Comment: @Joby it's because the Uno doesn't use an FTDI chip anymore. It uses an atmega8u2 instead. I believe this was done in order to provide hardware for HID support.

Comment: Thanks for the leg up on this. What about on a duemilanove or decimila?

Comment: They are older versions of UNO, right? and this technique was probably developed when they were around?

Comment: @Shubham please look at my comment on your question. You will find all the information you need in there.

Comment: I see, didn't see that before. Thank you!

Comment: @JGord I don't understand why changing from FTDI to 8u2 would affect the ArduinoISP sketch or the operation of the bootloader. Both chips are transparent serial to USB converters. I suspect that the ArduinoISP sketch will work just fine on Uno, but that it hasn't been well tested. http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1289761852/5#5

Comment: @Joby I don't see why that would affect it either, but the text is pretty unambiguous - it doesn't say it's untested, it says it doesn't work.

Comment: @Joby It is because of the way they used the DTR reset. The sketch does work with a tiny hardware modification if you look at the comment I posted on the question. Apparently, it has to do with current differences between the FTDI and the 8u2, not actually the firmware.

Comment: @Joby No prob, I think that's the first time I've actually been helpful on this site =)

Answer (score 4):

You can turn Arduino Uno in a true programmer / basic debugger using a code called TinyISP
You can program most AVRs with Arduino Uno and also debug the code.
See this forum discussion: 
http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,125248.0.html

Comment: http://pdp11.byethost12.com/AVR/ArduinoAsProgrammer.htm