# Is it possible to custom program AVR by putting it in the AVR socket of an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr

Is it possible to custom program an AVR chip by putting it in the AVR socket of an Arduino?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can program a virgin AVR by connecting it up to some GPIOs and reflashing it. If you had a second Arduino, the chip being programmed would sit in the socket.

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

(With the Arduino Uno, it's more complex it seems)

[Can you use an Arduino Uno as an ATMega328 Programmer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17452/can-you-use-an-arduino-uno-as-an-atmega328-programmer)

[How to burn atmega328 chip via Arduino UNO as ISP?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/how-to-burn-atmega328-chip-via-arduino-uno-as-isp)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Arduino with a FT232RL chip onbaord (Arduino Duemilanove or earlier models or their clones) then you can bitbang the FT232RL to program the bootloader or any other code into the AVR.

http://make.kosakalab.com/arduino/bootloader/index_en.html